# I need a proper English translating for this

Tags: c

accept user input via scanf() in the form of 4 hexadecimal digits. Your code will interpret this input as a 16-bit unsigned short. For each input item, your code should extract bits 6 through 9 and print out the unsigned numerical value of those bits

I had a sample that says: input is: abcd the result is: 15
i've be working on it but i was converting to decimal from hex and that was a different thing
i just want an explanation about what extract bits 6 to 9 is

Comment: A number is comprised of bits, a 16 bit one having 16: `0000 0000 0000 0000`, bits 6 to 9 means (assuming 1 indexed and reading right to left) the ones marked X here `0000 000X XXX0 0000`

Comment: for example this hex number: 1234 in binary is: 0001001000110100 taking the 6 to 9 is: 0001 which its numerical value is: 1 but the sample says its 8
so how?

Comment: In that case it looks like it's 0 indexed, so bits: `0000 00XX XX00 0000`

Answer (score 2):

```
0xabcd = 0b1010 1011 1100 1101
bits      --------98 7654 3210                                  
bits 6 to 9       11 11
```

and

```
 0b1111 == 0xf == 15
```

Comment: one more question if I'm taking input from the user and store it in unsinged short x: for example
how to convert that 1234 hex value to binary 
i can use switches but I can't take the input properly to do the switches on it like when i type to the console 1234 i tried to print out X the stored value was 1234000 and when i entered abcd the value of X was some random things, anyhelp with the scanf function?

Comment: @AramOmran https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Comment: I got it to work but can you give me a short answer on how to loop over
UNSINGED SHORT X[x];
to convert each index to binary i tried this but didn't work 
for(i=0; i < LIMIT; i++){
    if(hex[i]>='0' && hex[i]<='9'){
        switch (hex[i]) {
          case '0':
            binary = binary + '0000';